# Android capture back button

Tags: android

I want to capture the back button in some activity in order to ask the user if he wants to save the form data. Is this possible?

I would need something like (pseudocode):

```
 onBackButtonPressed{
    AlertDialog("Do you want to save?")
    if (OkPressed) {
      // do the saving
    }else{
      // Continue with the backButton action
    }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Why not save the data automatically for the user?

Comment: naXa - thanks for the link, I did not seem to find that question+answer when I was looking for a solution. Thank you. The solution I found there works. Make your comment an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()` in your activity

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    AlertDialog("Do you want to save?")
    if (OkPressed) {
      // do the saving
    }else{
      // Continue with the backButton action
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override an Activity's [`onBackPressed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method to achieve this. Construct your AlertDialog using the corresponding [builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).